# Loading a partial view with an Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, load

My homepage is about 25K by itself but I've got several PNG images on it that once fully loaded comes to about 2 MEG. I am thinking about initially loading up the page without any images (or without the banner which contains all the PNGs and some HTML) then once the page loads, use jQuery/Ajax request to load in the partial view (which contains the images and a bit more HTML). My question is, does the complete function of the ajax request only run once all the images have actually loaded? And, is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
I apologise for initially misunderstanding the question.
Your browser will load all non-graphical content into the DOM first, then proceed to load all images in. You will see the content before you see the images.

However, as a side-note, I suggest you do something with those 2MB of images, they would take a while to load, particularly on dial up connections.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the well known jQuery document ready;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //JS Script
    });
</script>
```

Executes the Javascript when the page is READY. I.E., When the page is ready to manipulate, but the images havn't necessarily loaded. In my opinion, there would be no point in remotely requesting the images at a later stage, because this just puts more load on the server, and, if anything, increases the overall load time of the page.
Rest assured that your JavaScript will be executed even if the images are not loaded.

Comment: I understand how the ready function works, what I want to do is load and display the rest of the page before having to wait for 2 MEG of PNGS to download.

Comment: I don't know, however if that is the case then there would be no need for me to proceed with the above plan.